# Recursive Components in AngularJS 1.x

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-components

Finally trying to learn AngularJS and I can't quite figure out how to make components work recursively. I have a simple [example](https://jsfiddle.net/sathomas/nxn6hvwb/1/) that's not rendering as expected.

#### HTML

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl as vm">
  <nested-list list="vm.list"></nested-list>
</body>
```

#### JavaScript

```
angular.module('myApp', [])

  .controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.list = [
      { "name": "Item 1" }, 
      { "name": "Item 2",
        "subItems": [
          { "name": " Item 2.1" }
        ]
      }, 
      { "name": "Item 3",
        "subItems": [
          { "name": " Item 3.1" }, 
          { "name": "Item 3.2",
            "subItems": [
              { "name": "Item 3.2.1" },
              { "name": "Item 3.2.2" }
            ]
          }
        ]
    }];
  }])

  .component('nestedList', {
    bindings: {
      list: '<'
    },
    template: `
      <div ng-repeat="item in $ctrl.list" >
        <div> {{item.name}} </div>
        <nested-list list="item.subItems"></nested-list>
      </div>
    `
  });
```

Undoubtedly because I'm missing something obvious, the list from the app's main controller `myCtrl` isn't getting bound to the root component. If anyone can provide insight, I'd be grateful.

Stephen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are using `controllerAs`, you should be binding values to controller `this`(context) instead of binding values to `$scope`.

```
.controller('myCtrl', [function() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.list = [ ..];
}]);
```

[**Plunker Here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/NCIkCX7p8t8AJPuqr71h?p=preview)

Comment: This is the correct answer. 
If you want to use $scope (which is not according best practices, and better not do do it), just change your html to: `<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <nested-list list="list"></nested-list>
</body>`
I added this comment because sometimes you should work with legacy code and better to follow all project styles, so you won't have 2 different styles in one project